# Maintaining Relative Scroll Position on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a long html document. When the window is resized, I'm trying to maintain the relative scroll position while the content is reflowed. For example, if the top of the page is on a paragraph midway down the page, after reducing the window to half its width, I want to keep the paragraph at the top of the window.

I've currently tried using js to maintain the relative scroll offset: https://jsfiddle.net/54xh3Ldy/1/

```
let pageHeight = 0

window.onload = () => {
  pageHeight = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height
}    

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const currentOffset = window.scrollY
  const newPageHeight = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height
  const dHeight = newPageHeight / pageHeight
  window.scrollTo(0, currentOffset * dHeight)
  pageHeight = newPageHeight
}, true)
```

This sort of works, but is pretty jittery. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Doesn't look that jittery to me...has anyone else told you it was "jittery"?

Comment: I mean...are users going to be incessantly resizing the window?  If not, what's the worry?

Comment: @ZackMacomber Yes, this is for an electron app where resizing is common

Comment: I'm also curious about this as well. When I design responsive layouts I'm resizing the viewport 100's and 1000's of times (kind of like how traditional cell-animators worked, flapping back and forth between drawings). Each time, the page length swings from super short to super long. If I'm fine-tuning a single object somewhere on the page, it's super annoying having to constantly re-scroll it into view after every resize. Perhaps this can be done in JS, but ultimately I'd like browser dev tools to have some kind of scroll-position-lock or keep-element-in-view-during-scroll type of feature.

Comment: I don't know if there is perfect solution. For example you could do something like find the top element that's on the screen when the user starts to resize and try to keep that element on the screen. That kind of works except for example if you have a really long paragraph then even though you'd been keeping that paragraph on the screen the only part of the paragraph that's stable is the first word. All other words could jump around as the text is reflowed. The same will be true of collections of photos etc. They'll jump up or down, left or right except for the 1st one in any section.